# Removing column seperator

Tags: tables, formatting, luatex

So I have this table, which has some empty space in it. How would I got about removing the separators there? Is it even possible with a regular table?

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\ruby{き}{ki} & \ruby{きゃ}{kya} & \ruby{きゅ}{kyu} & \ruby{きょ}{kyo} &
\ruby{ぎ}{gi} & \ruby{ぎゃ}{gya} & \ruby{ぎゅ}{gyu} & \ruby{ぎょ}{gyo} \\
\hline
\ruby{し}{shi} & \ruby{しゃ}{sha} & \ruby{しゅ}{shu} & \ruby{しょ}{sho} &
\ruby{じ}{ji} & \ruby{じゃ}{ja} & \ruby{じゅ}{ju} & \ruby{じょ}{jo} \\
\hline
\ruby{ち}{chi} & \ruby{ちゃ}{cha} & \ruby{ちゅ}{chu} & \ruby{ちょ}{cho} &
\ruby{ぢ}{ji} & \ruby{ぢゃ}{ja} & \ruby{ぢゅ}{ju} & \ruby{ぢょ}{jo} \\
\hline
\ruby{に}{ni} & \ruby{にゃ}{nya} & \ruby{にゅ}{nyu} & \ruby{にょ}{nyo} &
\ruby{み}{mi} & \ruby{みゃ}{mya} & \ruby{みゅ}{myu} & \ruby{みょ}{myo} \\
\hline
\ruby{ひ}{hi} & \ruby{ひゃ}{hya} & \ruby{ひゅ}{hyu} & \ruby{ひょ}{hyo} &
\ruby{び}{bi} & \ruby{びゃ}{bya} & \ruby{びゅ}{byu} & \ruby{びょ}{byo} \\
\hline
 & & & &
\ruby{ぴ}{pi} & \ruby{ぴゃ}{pya} & \ruby{ぴゅ}{pyu} & \ruby{ぴょ}{pyo} \\
\hline
\ruby{り}{ri} & \ruby{りゃ}{rya} & \ruby{りゅ}{ryu} & \ruby{りょ}{ryo} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Hiragana Digraphs}
\end{table}
```

So turning this:
[image: From this]
Into this:
[image]

I've tried multicolumn and such, but seem to be missing something.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome TeX.SE @tim-jager

Your separators are given by the vertical bars

```latex
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c|}
```

You have some around your empty cells, just remove them from the format specification

```latex
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c  c|c|c|c|}
```

Edit: didn't saw the images. You were not talking about the middle column but the last two rows.

```latex
\hline
 & & & 
& \ruby{ぴ}{pi} & \ruby{ぴゃ}{pya} & \ruby{ぴゅ}{pyu} & \ruby{ぴょ}{pyo} \\
\hline
\ruby{り}{ri} & \ruby{りゃ}{rya} & \ruby{りゅ}{ryu} & \ruby{りょ}{ryo} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}
\\
\hline
```

Give `\multicolumn` first argument the number of column to span over, and as second argument the formatting for the grouped columns, then as third argument your value (which is empty here)

```latex
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} % this cell will span over the four first columns...
& \ruby{ぴ}{pi} & \ruby{ぴゃ}{pya} & \ruby{ぴゅ}{pyu} & \ruby{ぴょ}{pyo} \\
\hline
\ruby{り}{ri} & \ruby{りゃ}{rya} & \ruby{りゅ}{ryu} & \ruby{りょ}{ryo} & 
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{} % this cell will cover the four last columns...
\\
\hline
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems I didn't fully understand how multicolumn worked, this was perfect.

Comment: You welcome @TimJager :) I've been in the same situation years ago.